# Top 3 sold qty in table for each item

Tags: sql, oracle

In my scenario I’ve table of  item sold quantity in oracle.  I want to apply a query to get the top 3 sold quantity of each item. What will be the query for this.

**Item_Sale Table**

```
item_No Sold_Qty
1   5
1   6
1   2
1   8
1   9
2   7
2   8
2   4
2   5
2   8
2   7
2   6
2   1
2   2
2   8
3   7
3   2
3   4
3   2
3   6
```

Now I want to see the Top 3 sold qty  of each item

Desired result is

```
item_no Top3_Sold_Qty
1   9
1   8
1   7
2   8
2   7
2   6
3   7
3   6
3   4
```

Comment: Please - don't **SHOUT AT US!** by writing in ALL CAPS - it's not only really hard to read, it's also rude and offensive - please stop doing it right now, and fix your title here - thank you

Comment: Did you try to write SQL query for it?

Comment: @user3068945 [Answer from user slavoo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20393359/1179699) is not right. Why? See comment below his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT item_No, Sold_Qty
FROM
(
  SELECT
    item_No, Sold_Qty,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY item_No ORDER BY Sold_Qty desc) rn
  FROM Item_Sale
)
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY item_No;
```

[fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7f410/3)

After comment (for distinct values):

```
SELECT DISTINCT item_No, Sold_Qty
FROM
(
   SELECT
     item_No, Sold_Qty,
     DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY item_No ORDER BY Sold_Qty desc) rn
   FROM Item_Sale
)
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY item_No;
```

Comment: Why you select `ROW_NUMBER()` from `Item_Sale`instead from `SELECT DISTINCT item_No, Sold_Qty FROM Item_Sale` like in my example below? If value in table `Item_Sale` not distinct then your query return wrong result.

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to select **distinct values**

```
SELECT item_No, Sold_Qty FROM
(SELECT item_No, Sold_Qty, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY iten_No ORDER BY Sold_Qty DESC) AS Rank FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT item_No, Sold_Qty FROM Item_Sale) Temp) Temp2
WHERE Rank< 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte as 
(
select item_no,Sold_qty,row_number() over (partition by item_no order by sold_qty desc) as rank1 from table
)

select * from cte where rank1<=3 order by item_no,Sold_qty desc
```